# How to send attachment + message body inside one Email

Tags: android, jakarta-mail, mime-message

I want to send email with body and attachment. My problem is i add those using `DataHandler`.

I can set only one, so if I put body, and then attachment, only attachment is arriving.

```
        try{
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(body, "text/plain");
            message.setDataHandler(handler);

            MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            if (absolutePath != null) {
                Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
                String file = absolutePath;
                String name = "podpis";
                if (fileName != null) name = fileName;
                name += ".jpg";
                DataSource source = new FileDataSource(file);
                messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
                messageBodyPart.setFileName(name);
                multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
                message.setContent(multipart);
            }

            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));
            else
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));
            Transport.send(message);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("GMAIL SENDER", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I've been looking for some answers or tips, but I'm not sure if it's me using wrong approach in research, or it's not so obvious.

Comment: You need to create two MimeBodyParts - one for the text and one for the attachment.  See the [sendfile.java](https://github.com/javaee/javamail/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/sendfile.java) sample program for a complete example.

Comment: You got beer from me mate :)